# New line in email by creating message from a cell value with line breaks: VBA

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am facing with the issue related to mail in VBA.

For Example. In cell A1 I have:

```
Test test test

test


test test
```

And when I am generating the mail from a cell A1, the string appears without the line breaks, I mean

```
Test test test test test test.
```

I tried to use Replace from `"\r\n"` to `"<br/>"` but that does not work.

```
Content = Replace(Content , "\r\n", "<br/>")
```

Can anybody help me resolve this?

Comment: I know that `Chr(10)` works as new line in e-mail body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is replacing Excel's newline character `Chr(10)` with the HTML line break `<br>`

Email code:

```
Sub mail()
    Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object, strbody As String

    ' Get string from cell, replace Chr(10) (the cell new line) with a html <br>
    strbody = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
    strbody = Replace(strbody, Chr(10), "<br>")

    ' Create email and add string as HTMLBODY item
    On Error Resume Next
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    With OutMail
        .to = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "Subject here"
        .htmlbody = strbody
        .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Ouput:

[image: test]

Comment: Working ! Thank you very much. +1